# How to access a google cloud virtual machine from a laptop with dual external monitors?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, ubuntu-14.04, google-compute-engine, dual-monitor

I am running a Ubuntu 14.04 System 76 laptop(laptop). Two external monitors are connected to this laptop.
I have configured a windows-server-2012-r2 Virtual Machine(VM) on the Google Compute Engine(GCE).
Two remote desktop(RDP) clients are installed on this Ubuntu laptop: Google Chrome Remote Desktop and Remmina.

How can I configure the windows GCE VM itself and either of these RDP clients on the Ubuntu Laptop to utilize at least the two external monitors to access the VM?
If I could use all three monitors (two external and the laptop), it would be awesome.

The script used to create the VM is below:

gcloud compute --project "your-project-here" instances create "your-vm-name-here" --zone "us-central1-c" --machine-type "n1-highcpu-8" --network "default" --maintenance-policy "MIGRATE" --image "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/windows-cloud/global/images/windows-server-2012-r2-dc-v20150909" --boot-disk-size "50" --no-boot-disk-auto-delete --boot-disk-type "pd-ssd" --boot-disk-device-name "your-vm-name-here"

Comment: Any luck on this?

Answer (score 1):

Remmina and Chrome RDP only support Full screen mode and don't support multi monitor at the moment. You can install FreeRDP:

```
sudo apt-get install freerdp-x11
```

and use the following command from the terminal:

```
xfreerdp /multimon /u:username /v:server_address:server_port
```

where `username` is your username on server, `server_address` is server location (IP address or hostname) and `server_port` is port (leave empty without ":" for default port)

Comment: Consistently get ERRCONNECT_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED [0x20009] [com.freerdp.core] for Google Compute Engine server. Specifying /d for domain as well and even after every combination tried - still unsuccessful.

Comment: @MikeMurko the error that you are mentioning is related to FreeRDP, and this is normally caused by a mistake in UserName/Password. It can also be caused by checking/unchecking the Activate Network Level Authentication check box in the connection tab of the session.